# Apply a correction factor to one column based on the value of a second column

Tags: r

Example Data

```
A<-c(1,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,7)
B<-c(4,6,7,8,2,2,2,3,8,8,7,8)
DF<-data.frame(A,B)
```

What I would like to do is apply a correction factor to column A, based on the values of column B. The rules would be something like this

```
If B less than 4  <- Multiply A by 1
If B equal to  4 and less than 6  <- Multiply A by 2
If B equal or greater than 6 <-  Multiply by 4
```

I suppose I could write an "if" statement (and I'd be glad to see a good example), but I'd also be interested in using square bracket indexing to speed things up.

The end result would look like this

```
A  B
2  4
16 6
20 7
24 8
```

ect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
within(DF, A <- ifelse(B>=6, 4, ifelse(B<4, 1, 2)) * A)
```

Or this (corrected by @agstudy):

```
within(DF, {A[B>=6] <- A[B>=6]*4; A[B>=4 & B<6] <- A[B>=4 & B<6]*2})
```

Benchmarking:

```
DF <- data.frame(A=rpois(1e4, 5), B=rpois(1e4, 5))
a <- function(DF) within(DF, A <- ifelse(B>=6, 4, ifelse(B<4, 1, 2)) * A)
b <- function(DF) within(DF, {A[B>=6] <- A[B>=6]*4; A[B>=4 & B<6] <- A[B>=4 & B<6]*2})

identical(a(DF), b(DF))
#[1] TRUE

microbenchmark(a(DF), b(DF), times=1000)
#Unit: milliseconds
#  expr      min        lq   median        uq      max neval
# a(DF) 8.603778 10.253799 11.07999 11.923116 53.91140  1000
# b(DF) 3.763470  3.889065  5.34851  5.480294 39.72503  1000
```

Comment: +1! for 2 vectorized solutions and a benchmarking. FYI `transform` and `within` have the similar benchmarks.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Ferdinand solution but using `transform`

```
transform(DF, newcol = ifelse(B<4,  A,
                                   ifelse(B>=6,4*A,2*A)))
      A B newcol
1  1 4      2
2  4 6     16
3  5 7     20
4  6 8     24
5  2 2      2
6  3 2      3
7  4 2      4
8  5 3      5
9  6 8     24
10 7 8     28
11 8 7     32
12 7 8     28
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use `findInterval` as an index into a set of factors for such operations. The proliferation of nested test-conditional and consequent vectors with multiple `ifelse` calls offends my efficiency sensibilities:

```
 DF$A <- DF$A * c(1,2,4)[findInterval(DF$B, c(-Inf,4,6,Inf) ) ]
 DF
    A B
1   2 4
2  16 6
3  20 7
4  24 8
snipped ....
```

Benchmark:

```
DF <- data.frame(A=rpois(1e4, 5), B=rpois(1e4, 5))
a <- function(DF) within(DF, A <- ifelse(B>=6, 4, ifelse(B<4, 1, 2)) * A)
b <- function(DF) within(DF, {A[B>=6] <- A[B>=6]*4; A[B>=4 & B<6] <- A[B>=4 & B<6]*2})
ccc <- function(DF) within(DF, {A * c(1,2,4)[findInterval(B, c(-Inf,4,6,Inf) ) ]})
microbenchmark(a(DF), b(DF), ccc(DF), times=1000)
#-----------
Unit: microseconds
    expr      min        lq    median        uq      max neval
   a(DF) 7616.107 7843.6320 8105.0340 8322.5620 93549.85  1000
   b(DF) 2638.507 2789.7330 2813.8540 3072.0785 92389.57  1000
 ccc(DF)  604.555  662.5335  676.0645  698.8665 85375.14  1000
```

Note: I would not have done this using `within` if I were coding my own function, but thought for fairness to the earlier effort, I would make it apples <-> apples.